# To pass an integer variable which varies dynamically from an adapter class to an activity

Tags: android, listview, variables, android-intent, custom-adapter

I'm trying to pass an Integer variable from listView Adapter Class(extends BaseAdapter) to an Activity(ActionBarActivity). This should be done inside an onClickListener. Can anyone please help solving this issue.

```
holder1.companyName_textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(activity, "CpsID: "
                    + searchresultList.get(position).getCpsId(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Company Name: "
                    + searchresultList.get(position).getCpsName(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Intent intent = new Intent(activity, CompanyProfile_Activity.class);
            intent.putExtra("companyCpsId", searchresultList.get(position).getCpsId());
            activity.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Also please explain how to receive it in my activity class.

Comment: what you need to receive in your activity class? you are passing it to CompanyProfile_Activity class at present, what is the value of variable activity?

Comment: do you have any problem in passing this integer to the specified activity..? if no you can receive the value using   getIntent().getIntExtra("companyCpsId")

Comment: Here "activity" is the reference name of the context

Comment: in my activity it shows like this.."cpsId = intent.getIntExtra(name, defaultValue);"
here what should I give for "defaultValue"

Comment: it depends on your dynamically changing values limit ... better use anyone of these Integer.MAX_VALUE =  2147483647
Integer.MIN_VALUE = -2147483648

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class CompanyProfile_Activity extends Activity{


    int default_value=0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        int value=getIntent().getIntExtra("companyCpsId", default_value);
        Toast.makeText(CompanyProfile_Activity.this,"Id: "+value, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



    }

}
```

**And don't forget to add these code into AndroidManifest.xml file**

```
<activity
        android:name=".CompanyProfile_Activity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this if you want to communicate between adapter and current activity
create interface like

```
public interface OnItemValueChange{
 public void onValueChange(String value);
}
```

Use

```
YourActivity implement OnItemValueChange
```

While creating your adapter pass this interface reference to your adapter like

```
adapter.setOnValueChangeListener(this);
```

Save this interface reference in your adapter  and whenever you want to send some data call

```
interfaceReference.onValueChange("text");
```

Above method is located in your activity
**Edit**
Use if you want to get value in new activity

```
int id =  getIntent().getIntExtra("CompanyCsId");
```